# Error In Xlrd module

Tags: xlrd, xlsxwriter

apologies for my long description. i am not left with any options...

basically, i have written a XML parser in python. which extracts the data from XML tag and writes the data in to Excel sheet using xlsxwriter module. once the excel sheet is created i read the data in excel using xlrd package,process the data and then update my result based on condition in the same excel in result column. now, my problem is, when the Excel is already created and present in the path my program is just working fine but when i delete the Excel and run the program it throws an error as below:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "AMS_parse.py", line 71, in <module>
rworkbook = xlrd.open_workbook('AMS.xlsx')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 394, 
    in open_workbook
f = open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AMS.xlsx'
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor.
Explicit close() may be required for workbook.',) 
    in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of 
    <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x0297E450>
```

**My program is as below:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
# create a work book AMS.xlsx
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('AMS.xlsx')
# create a worksheet "AMSLogging" in work book AMS.xlsx
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("AMSLogging")
# format the work sheet
format = workbook.add_format({'bold': 25,'font_color': 'green'})
worksheet.write('A1','Component',format)
worksheet.write('B1','DataType',format)
worksheet.write('C1','PrivateData',format)
worksheet.write('D1','Result',format)
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 15)
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 25)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 40)
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 50)
#create a tree for AMS.xml
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='AMS.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print "PLEASE CHECK THE RESULT IN THE SAME WORKING DIRECTORY OF THE FILE AMS.XLSX AND AMSMISCLOGGING.TXT"
#set the row to 1'st row since 0th row is Headline
row = 1
#set the column to zero'th column 
col = 0
#get the Component values from the XML
for Component in tree.iter(tag='Component'):    
    worksheet.write_string(row,col,Component.text)  
    row = row+1
#reset row to 1st row to start it from the first row for writing Datatype values
row = 1
for DataType in tree.iter(tag='DataType'):
    worksheet.write_string(row,col+1,DataType.text)
    row = row+1
#reset row to 1st row to start it from the begining for writing PrivateData values
row = 1
for PrivateData in tree.iter(tag='PrivateData'):
    worksheet.write_string(row,col+2,PrivateData.text)
    row = row+1

#---------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------
rworkbook = xlrd.open_workbook('AMS.xlsx')
sheet = rworkbook.sheet_by_index(0)
rrow = sheet.nrows
ccol = sheet.ncols
print "row:%d column:%d" %(rrow,ccol)

# set the row to 1 to start from the first row
row=1
x = 1

while x < rrow:
    for y in range(ccol):
        if sheet.cell_value(x,y) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+1) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+2) == '0301':
            worksheet.write(row,col+3,"PF banner is launched")
        elif sheet.cell_value(x,y) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+1) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+2) == '0302':
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+3,"Guide is launched")
        elif sheet.cell_value(x,y) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+1) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+2) == '0402':
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+3,"Guide is Dismissed")
        elif sheet.cell_value(x,y) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+1) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+2) == '0401':
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+3,"PF banner is Dismissed")
        elif sheet.cell_value(x,y) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+1) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+2) == '0316':
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+3,"SHOWCASE Menu is launched")
        elif sheet.cell_value(x,y) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+1) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+2) == '0416':
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+3,"SHOWCASE Menu is Dismissed")
        elif sheet.cell_value(x,y) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+1) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+2) == '0317':
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+3,"ACTVE Menu is Launched")
        elif sheet.cell_value(x,y) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+1) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+2) == '0417':
            worksheet.write_string(row,col+3,"ACTVE Menu is Dismissed")
    row = row+1
    x = x+1

#Close the work book after writing
try:
    workbook.close()
except:
    # Handle your exception here.
    print("please close the AMS.xlsx file")
```

please throw some light on how to correct the error.

Comment: It looks like the file xlsx file you are trying to read isn't in the directory you are running the program from.

Comment: but i am creating the work book before reading and still getting an error.

Comment: Hi jmcnamara, kindly advise me on how to proceed fwd

Comment: The file isn't created until you execute `workbook.close()`, so you cannot write to the file and read from it at the same time. Wit that in mind you should restructure your code or re-ask the question to state what you are trying to do.

Comment: is there any method in xlswriter that allows me open the pre-existing file created ?

Comment: No. XlsxWriter can only create a new file. OpenPyxl allows you to open an existing file. However I think you should look at the problem again: *"writes the data in to Excel sheet using xlsxwriter module. once the excel sheet is created i read the data in excel using xlrd package,process the data and then update my result based on condition"* If you are writing information to the Excel file then you have it available in your Python program and you don't need to re-read the file to get it. You could for example use a formula in the Excel file that you are writing.

Comment: i could able to solve the issues by using openPyxl module. thanks jmcnamara for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close `workbook` before opening `rworkbook`. 
In fact, you shouldnt use a reader, make your calculations in `workbook` directly.

Comment: Hi Ruben, when i close the workbook before reading then i will not able to write the data in to work book which i am doing in the belwo code: while x < rrow:
    for y in range(ccol):
        if sheet.cell_value(x,y) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+1) == '1' and sheet.cell_value(x,y+2) == '0301':
            worksheet.write(row,col+3,"PF banner is launched")